# How do I loop until one of two variables reaches zero

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I want to first get a random number (`probability`) from 0-1, and then according to if that number (`probability`) is <= 0.6, I want it to add 1 to variable `y` (whose initial value is 2) and subtract 1 from variable `x` (whose initial value is 10). If it's > 0.6, I want it to add 1 to variable `x` (whose initial value is 10) and subtract 1 from variable `y` (whose initial value is 2). I have the following code intending to repeatedly perform the procedure I described above until one of the variables (`x` and `y`) reaches 0?

public class Cat {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double probability = Math.random();
    int x=10,y=2;


for (x = 10; x <= 0; x--)
for (y = 2; y <= 0; y--)
    if (probability <= 0.6) {
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(x);
    }   

    else if (probability > 0.6){
        System.out.println(++x);
        System.out.println(--y);

    }   
    }
```

Comment: please re-post your question once you have coded something rather than asking for the solution... take some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What programming language?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm using java, and yes I have tried. I will post what I have so far

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double probability;
    int x=10,y=2;


while( y > 0 && x>0)
{
    probability = Math.random();
    if (probability <= 0.6) {
        System.out.println(++y);
        System.out.println(--x);
    }   

    else if (probability > 0.6){
        System.out.println(++x);
        System.out.println(--y);

    }
}
```

Comment: It is done through single loop and random number should be generated inside loop i think but if your problem statement requires it to be generated only once then place it before the loop.